# select all columns from 1 table, 1 column from a second table, using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dapper

I am presently pulling records from a details table using Dapper. I do "select * from details ..." and it works fine. On a select call I generally get 1 - 3 rows (due to the where clause).

I now need to also get one value from the table parent where parent.id (PK) == details.parentId. I can do a join to get all of this and I'm assuming Dapper would have no problem.

But, I want to keep the "select *" for the details class select. Otherwise anytime columns are added/removed I need to update the select. Is there a way to do this where I get * from details and just parent.discount from the parent table?

Answer (score 0):

you put `sql-server` so here goes nothing

```
select d.*
    ,  p.discount
from details d join parent p 
     on d.parentId = p.id 
where ...
```

good luck

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need. I'm rebuilding a library and so will be able to test in a couple of days. thanks.